# PHP array to an Array of Objects

Tags: php, json

how would I convert my array to an array of objects with PHP ?

input

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

output

```
[ {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3} ]
```

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: And which object is that?

Comment: that's what I'm here looking for

Comment: @tommy123 Welcome on SO. SO is not a code writing service. Please consider to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so a basic concept isn't enough to get the message across ?... you need the four lines of code that I current have ? I think people that know PHP already know more than enough to understand the question.

Comment: @tommy123 *you need the four lines of code that I current have ?* Yes!, 1. It improves the quality of your question 2. We see where you are stuck and can explain more what exactly you did wrong and how you fix it 3. We see that we don't just do your job! (Maybe you want to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3933332)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined your object before, I guess I'd do a loop

```
     class previouslyDefinedObject{
       public $id;
     }
     $myArray = array(1,2,3);
     $newArray = array();
     foreach($myArray as $id){
       $obj = new previouslyDefinedObject();
       $obj->id = $id;
       array_push($newArray, $obj);
     }
     print_r($newArray);
```

That way, your $newArray will contains every object in an array

Answer (score 2):

When you have to reformat array, e.g. transorm values of the array to another format (number to object with id->number) and they map 1:1 (the new array have the same number of elements like the original), [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) is the solution

```
$newArray = array_map(function($item) {
  $object = new \StdClass;
  $object->id = $item;
  return $object;
}, $array);
```

Comment: I don't have enough rep to up vote you but thanks.